# ContentPresenter and GridViewRowPresenter cannot be in each other inclusively or exclusively

Tags: wpf

How to build the controls in code below?.

```
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- Принципиальные схемы -->
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding principlies}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
                              ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectContentExpander}">
                    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource principlies}"/>
                    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </StackPanel>
```

error: In a FrameworkTemplate, ContentPresenter and GridViewRowPresenter cannot be in each other inclusively or exclusively.
Error disappears if you remove Style block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          <StackPanel>
                <Border>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding principlies}" 
                                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ProjectContentExpander}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource principlies}"/>
                        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                 </Border> 
          </StackPanel>
```

solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

I assume the *principlies* is a x:Key for a DataTemplate, defined in the xaml, but DataTemplate (which inherits FrameworkTemplate) cannot be set as a content. That's why you get this exception. Moreover, the ContentPresenter.Content property is data-bound for *principles*, which expect a DependencyObject or a data item coming from the source.

Please, excuse me if I missunderstood your question. Providing some more xaml will definetely shed some light.

Regards

Comment: principlies is a field of DataContext of the UserControl where are placed code above. Error disappears if you remove Style block.